# Group bar chart data not working as expected

Tags: json, svg, d3.js

Have an array set of the type json object.
Var data has an array object like:

```
0: Object
letter  : A
frequency : .08167
1: Object
letter  : B
frequency : .01492
2: Object
letter  : C
frequency : .02780
3: Object
letter  : A
frequency : .06167
4: Object
letter  : D
frequency : .02492
5: Object
letter  : C
frequency : .03780
```

The field letter has more than one set of data(for ex: letter A is having two sets of frequency or more). I need to create a group chart for the same.

```
var frequency= d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function (key) {
                return (key !== "letter");
            });
            data.forEach(function (d) {
                d.val = frequency.map(function (name) { return { name: name, value: +d[name] }; });
            });
```

This doesn't seem to work. Is there anything wrong in the structure of `Json` data?

Comment: Could you explain what you want your grouped bar chart to look like? Are you grouping by letter along the x-axis, and showing frequency on the y-axis? If so, how do you distinguish between the two different `A` values? And will each letter-group not be the same size?

Comment: Comparing it with previous year value. So I need X axis to read letters names grouped by comparision of frequencies based on years.

0: Object
letter  : A
frequency : .08167
Year :2015
1: Object
letter  : B
frequency : .01492
Year :2015
2: Object
letter  : C
frequency : .02780
Year :2015
3: Object
letter  : A
frequency : .06167
Year :2014
4: Object
letter  : D
frequency : .02492
5: Object
letter  : C
frequency : .03780
Year :2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question and comment, it seems like you have your data in a format like this:

```
data = [
{ "letter": "A", "frequency": .08167, "year": 2015}, 
{ "letter": "B", "frequency": .01492, "year": 2015},
{ "letter": "C", "frequency": .02780, "year": 2015}...
```

In which case, the best way to group by letter for your grouped bar chart would be to use `d3.nest`:

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
    .key(function (d) {
        return d.letter;
    })
    .entries(data);
```

which will structure your data with multiple `values` under each letter `key`.

Here's a working fiddle with your data: **http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/jc0nohhb/1/**, that borrows a lot from this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051

[image: barchartgrouped]

Note - This is a good resource to read more about `nest` in d3: http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/

Comment: Thank you @Henry. Will try now with the solution :)